# NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR property is blank in CustomAction while Removing

Tags: wix

We are using a custom action to unregister .dll using regasm.exe in WiX. The condition of custom action is to execute only when REMOVE="ALL" i.e it will execute in uninstall and remove process. My custom action is failing to execute in Remove process.

```
    <CustomAction Id='SetMyAction'
             Property='MyProperty'
             Value='&quot;[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]\regasm.exe&quot; /s /u &quot;[TestDir]Test.dll&quot;'
             Execute='immediate'/>
   <CustomAction Id="MyProperty" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>
             <InstallExecuteSequence>
                <Custom Action="SetMyAction" After="InstallInitialize">REMOVE="ALL" </Custom>
                <Custom Action="MyProperty" After="SetMyAction">REMOVE="ALL" </Custom>
             </InstallExecuteSequence>

In log file, it shows 
Action 12:20:48: SetMyAction.C34534B3_2456_4073_BC06_716E54E09F7D. 
MSI (s) (94:10) [12:20:48:672]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=SetMyAction.C34534B3_2456_4073_BC06_716E54E09F7D,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=CAQuietExec,CustomActionData="\regasm.exe" /s /u "C:\Test\Test.dll")
MSI (s) (94:AC) [12:20:48:727]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI2882.tmp, Entrypoint: CAQuietExec
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: Command failed to execute.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: CAQuietExec Failed
```

That means [NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR] property is not populated in CustomActionData.

Does it requires admin privileges or missing something else in custom action...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in that NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR was blank when adding an iis:WebServiceExtension.

I found I had to explicitly define it with `<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR"/>` in my Product.wxs.

It was then populated correctly framework location.